# Remove last digits in price decimals. Wordpress(PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with my Wordpress site. There is pricebox, which shows the price in decimals.

Example:
When i type - 249£ it shows like 249.00£ i just want to remove the decimals.

here is the PHP code

```
$key_fields[] = array(
    'id'    => 'premium-period',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'title'      => __( 'Premium Period', 'pbs-client' ),
    'subtitle'   => __( 'Enter the price of premium membership', 'pbs-client'),
    'desc'       => __( 'Field has to be numeric and cannot be empty', 'pbs-client' ),
    'default'    => '249',
    'section_id' => 'premium-setup',
    'validate'   => 'numeric',
);
```

Comment: Java is not PHP. Please change tags

Comment: You know, usually Java is yet another programming language...

Comment: This question is not easily understandable. It is not obvious what your code is about. The decimals could come from the database, when sent to the client, or they could be rendered in the front-end.

Comment: Where are you outputting the price? Is the `£` a part of the string your getting or do you appending it when you output the price? It makes a huge difference for what answer you're looking for.

Comment: Chill , how should i know. i just removed tag "java"

Comment: _"Chill , how should i know"_ - Before posting, you should know what language you're asking about. That's not really too much to ask for.

Comment: Folks, calm down a bit. Zariiney, welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that this site is a bit different from the average web forum, so be sure to take the [tour] and read our guide [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you akraf, i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If its showing decimal after storing value in database then probably your column type is FLOAT, please change it to INT.

or where the value is echoing add this,

round($val, 0);

Comment: I think we should wait until the OP clarifies the question before writing answers. Otherwise, any answer will simply be guesses.

Comment: How do i find that column type from?

Comment: Magnus Eriksson. I dont simply understand what you guys are asking for.
I type 249 , in my page "pricing" in the price box it shows like 249.00 I want to remove the last decimals?

Comment: i just shared according to what i could get from the question. You can wait

Comment: Database, using phpmyadmin or sqlyog. if you have database access

Comment: @Zariiney - _"it shows like 249.00"_ - Where? In the input box? You need to explain the complete flow. What do you enter where and when and where does it show up like 249.00?

Comment: In my WP dashboard, they made a feature where i can type the number in!
Price: 249 

When i go the site where my prices are " it shows as 249.00 "

Frontend: 249.00
backend'ish: 249

Comment: change your database column to INT thats all. it'll solve your problem

Comment: I think it is on INT. But i found this.

<h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Master package', 'pbs-client' ); ?></h3>
                                <span><?php echo sprintf( '<span>%s</span>%s', $option['payments-currency'], $option['premium-price'] . '.00' ) ?></span>
                                <span><?php esc_html_e( 'per month', 'pbs-client' ); ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="package-description">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">